# How to minify JS in laravel mix without add suffix .min.js?

Tags: laravel, minify, laravel-mix

I tried use minify method like below:

```
    mix.minify('public/js/folder/script1.js');
    mix.minify('public/js/folder/script2.js');
```

but it will create `script1.min.js` and `script2.min.js`

I also tried :

```
    mix.minify('public/js/folder/script1.js', 'public/js/folder/script1.js');
    mix.minify('public/js/folder/script2.js', 'public/js/folder/script2.js');
```

and still create same files. How to minify without add suffix `.min.js?`

Comment: What's the problem with the name? Why it's bothering?

Comment: @OMiShah I want to minify all js on existing project that has same `<script src` on dev and prod , it's will pain if I change every blade files, so I want to use Laravel mix to do that.

Comment: Why can't you use `mix.js` ? Then in your blade you use `mix('js/folder/script1.js')` and you don't even have to bother about the final name, if you do `npm run dev` it will not be minified, if you run `npm run prod` it will automatically minify it, but `mix()` will get the correct file, no need for you to do anything else... Read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting)...

Comment: @matiaslauriti I tried on my project and that doesnt work, only worked on `js` folder only, but not work on subfolder, it's strange behaviour, worked on my another project but not on current project.

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur what did you try ? Show us as that is the way to go

Comment: @matiaslauriti thanks for your concern, but I don't have time to write it at yet and the problem is solved, maybe I will create new question next time if I want really laravel-mix solution

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I can't found laravel-mix solution, so I used another solution using [uglifyjs-folder](https://github.com/ionutvmi/uglifyjs-folder) :

```
 npm install uglifyjs-folder --save-dev
```

add `&& uglifyjs-folder public/js -e -x .js -o public/js` to package.js inside prod script like below:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production && uglifyjs-folder public/js -e -x .js -o public/js",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
```

it will minify all `.js` files on `public/js` folder after running `npm run prod`.

Maybe it's not the best practice, but it worked for existing project that already bad practice;